# JFrame not displaying when fullscreen JFrame is active

Tags: java, jframe, fullscreen

I have some `JFrames` in fullscreen with this code:

```
GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().setFullScreenWindow(Splashscreen);
```

But when I try to display a `JFrame` with a specific size, it won't display if the other JFrame is in fullscreen mode. How can I fix that?

code of non-fullscreen `JFrame`:

```
public void AppmenuGUI() {

    JFrame Appmenu = new JFrame("Appmenu");
    Appmenu.setSize(300, 500);
    Appmenu.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Appmenu.setUndecorated(true);
    Container c = Appmenu.getContentPane();
    c.setBackground(Color.red);
    Appmenu.setLocation(0, ScreenSize.screenheight - 300 - 50);
    Appmenu.setVisible(true);
    Appmenu.toFront();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting Appmenu.toFront(); before Appmenu.setVisible(true);?

Comment: I just tried, it didn't work :(